# Reading part of a string

Tags: python

Here I have part of a bigger program I am working on. This function is looking at some input emails and ordering them by alphabetical order. Is there a way I can make it look at only the part before the @domain? Currently I think it is looking at the whole input email string.

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if (self.email < other.email):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? I would recommend researching string splitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    return self.email[:self.email.index('@')] < other.email[:other.email.index('@')]
```

given there is always an `'@'` in `email`.

Here we work with *slicing*: we determine the index where the `'@'` sign is placed with `.index('@')` and we slice with `[:...]` up to (but excluding) the `'@'` sign. So:

```
>>> email='foo@bar.com'
>>> email[:email.index('@')]
'foo'
```

And then we simply calculate whether "our" part before the `'@'` sign is less than the part for the `'@'` sign of `other`.

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, would it be generally more accepted coding practice to use slicing notation like this as opposed to string splitting like `self.email.split('@')[0]`?  They should produce equivalent results in this case but their may be some special case where one method is better than the other that I am not aware of.

Comment: @tmwilson26: if the string does **not** contain an `@`, the split will still work whereas the slicing will fail. So yeah `split` can be better. Furthermore a split (can) be computationally more expensive since you calculate all split elements and not just the first one (you are actually interested in).

Comment: Understood, that makes it clear where the advantage could lie using slicing.

Comment: @tmwilson26: well of course it depends on the application. Say you want to do some fancy stuff with the domain, splitting can be a valid option. So there is evidently no "better" method in general. Otherwise one should not define the other one :).

Comment: Certainly.  I'm always on the lookout for new methods and tools for various applications though, so this will have to be added to the tool bag.  :)